# Using a Telerik control inside a repeater

Tags: telerik, repeater

I am using the asp.net Repeater control.  (My company is heavily invested in that, so I can't change it.)

I need a way to create a poup edit window, specific to the row the user clicked on in the repeater, so the user can edit the data in that record.

We have the Telerik controls to use, but I don't know which one.  I saw the radwindow, but can find no examples of using it in a repeater.  Frankly, Telerik documentation is confusing.

I prefer to use client-side code, ajax and web-services.  I'd like to prevent post-backs.

1) Please give me a reference to a specific example of using the Telerik radwindow inside a repeater for this purpose.

OR

2) Clue me in to a better idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are explicit examples with an asp Repeater, but I found [this one with a GridView](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/usingurlforserverarguments/defaultcs.aspx). The approach should be the same, as it is just another databound control - it shows an easy way to open a RadWindow on the client by passing some parameters (it is actually not possible to open it on the server, it is a client-side object).

Some more complex examples I found on their site [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/internalcontent/defaultcs.aspx) and [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window). They both update a grid, yet they show a nice way to use AJAX to prevent a full postback.

Comment: Thank you very much for the links.  They look like what I need.  What is (and especially what IS NOT) available is what is hard to find in the Telerik documentation, so your answer helps.